# request timed out for WCF service using nettcpbinding

Tags: wcf, service, nettcpbinding

I am new to WCF services, i have created a sample WCF service, where i have Hosted WCF Service with netTcpBinding in Windows Service.(since i want this WCF service to run as windows service)

Its a simple service which adds/deletes/loads employee details, and is consumed by a windows forms application.i don't know why, only 10 requests are responded, no matter what you do.The 11th request gives an error "request timed-out"

i know that increasing the time-out time wont help, it would just make me wait longer for that error.
i also know that my server(currently-local pc) is not responding for the 11th request, but don't know the reason.

Is there any setting for number of request/responses per minute for server? might sound funny, but i have no idea.

More useful info on the issue:

- Can't change the binding other than nettcp (system requirement)
- Logged in as Admin
- Firewall disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the connections aren't being closed - the default limit for WCF connections is 10, so the 11th won't work.

It might be that you're not explicitly closing them see here:

- http://devcatharsis.blogspot.com/2008/09/wcf-refusing-connections-after-10.html
- http://geekswithblogs.net/marcel/archive/2007/05/01/112159.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi KevD, that really worked! great, 
thanks very much...i really appreciate it :)

Comment: btw: in .NET 4 this limit was increased to 100 x number of cores

Comment: @Richard, i also found that the number of connections can be configured in app.config, where default value is `maxConnections="10"` in all the framework versions , don't know the limit though.

Comment: I was referring to the session throttle that was most likely the cause here as netTcp is a session based binding